# Where do I start with C#?

Tags: c#

I am wanting to learn C# where would be a good place to start?

What tools will I need to code and compile with as well?

Comment: See this question for some ideas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077315/starting-out-with-net-asp-net-wpf-silverlight-or-command-line-c

Comment: It depends on your general experience level.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with C#? Web programming? Windows Programming?

Comment: What is your past experience with programming?  Do you understand OOP concepts?

Comment: I have very little in the way of experiance I will be wanting to do to windows  programming.

Comment: This question has to be a duplicate

Comment: You start at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CSC.EXE /?` and understand the C# compiler exists and has options (like other compilers) before you open Visual Studio and never see the compiler again.

Answer (score 8):

Tools - Download [MS Visual C# Express Edition 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/).

Books - [Head First C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514824) if you are looking basics..

Refer this page for some [good videos and links on C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336766.aspx)

Comment: I've always found videos as a good learning tool. Plus you can do boring tasks on the side.

Comment: Likeing the vidoes I seem to learn better with a Vid than books it seems to sink in better.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't rely on the web for good code examples...**

With C# specifically, it's easy to find a million examples of how to do something but it's especially hard to find 'good' examples that are succinct and up-to-date with the latest features/practices of the language. If you're learning C# from scratch, the web will probably discourage more than help (I know from personal experience).

If you're learning C# rely on good books to get a solid start. [Here's a good list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-c) of books to begin with.

Also, bookmark [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpFundamentals.aspx) site as an online C# reference. It is by-far the best of the hundreds/thousands of C# sites that I have seen.

Comment: yes yes yes, agreed, use book resources to learn c#, they are guided and structured.... use the web for supplementary info!

Answer (score -1):

Download [Visual Studio Express edition 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/) and do a [Hello World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program) console application.

I'd also recommend downloading [SQL Server 2008 express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/) and getting familiar with that once you feel like you are getting good with C#.

Both are free and there is lots of resources out there for a beginner.

Also, if you work at a .NET shop tell your manager that you'd interested and see if he'll team you up with an experienced developer to get you started.  Having someone to teach you is extremely helpful.

Comment: When I was starting out I found the Hello World app to be rather unhelpful.

Comment: What was the first program you wrote in C#?

Comment: Its been a while but I believe that it was a little storyboard app. It kept a list of images that were linked to words and as you type a story out when you hit a keyword it replaced the word with an image. Nothing fancy but it really boosted my confidence.

Answer (score -2):

Download [Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/), start reading [books](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c%23+book+introduction&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) and [tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c%23+tutorial+introduction&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) and arm yourself with patience.

Answer (score -2):

I defiantly would say it depends on your experience level. If you already know the OO fundamentals like Polymorphism, Encapsulation etc... and programming fundamentals like loops, conditionals etc... then perhaps opt for a Pro book [Wrox C# 4.0](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-C-4-0-and-NET-4.productCd-0470502258.html). However if you are not familiar and have little experience I have to agree with others that the [Head First Series](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514822) is an extremely good way to learn. Not written in an Academic manner but in a more fun way which makes it easier to remember things.

Obviously as others suggested you can get the appropriate software to create applications in the form of the express editions.

I would try and create your own applications along with doing the books to make things fun and learn more. By doing this you can look at examples on the web and use the code trying to understand it, and also alter the code so it performs the functionality you want. Even if its functionality you have no idea about and the book hasn't covered, as long as you can look at the code and get a general idea of what it's doing.

Answer (score -2):

Like the above mentioned Visual studio 2010.

[try this](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx)  for a great starter, it has loads of resources.
Get familiar with the api, the sooner the better.
I also find video tutorials a great way to let the stuff stick :) So either watch video tutorials then code a bit , then watch again to remember it, but the best way to learn the code is just to do it. Too much theory can confuse, code as you go, set goals for your self and the theory will come as you try to figure out and solve problems.

Answer (score -2):

After installing VS2010 Express Edition, get *Programming in the Key of C#* by Charles Petzold.  It's ancient, but nothing teaches the fundamentals of C# like this book.  After that, get *Essential C# 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0*, higher the better.
Just take your time and learn the fundamentals down cold and you'll be ready to move on.

Answer (score -2):

Check out Microsoft's MSDN series of tutorials.

There's a [nice section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) that goes over command-line C# writing, as well as [another section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301562%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) that covers the drag-and-drop window designer functionality that you get with Visual Studio.